# How to bind an ItemsSource to a private property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How to bind WPF an `ItemsSource` to a private property?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="xxx" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ItemName"/>
```

```
public partial class ItemBuySellAddEdit : BasePage
{
    private List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Items list will be populated while the form loads.

Comment: public/internal works with binding.

Answer (score 22):

DataBinding in WPF works only with public properties.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes):

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation

Comment: Use ObservableCollection<T> instead of List<T>

Answer (score 4):

If you really really wanted to do this, you would have to provide a custom type descriptor, by implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` - that provides the extra property via a custom `PropertyDescriptor` alongisde the regular public properties. You can implement this interface on the type itself, or via `TypeDescriptionProvider`; the latter is preferred, as it works in more scenarios (things like empty lists, without needing to also provide a custom list with an `ITypedList` implementation). This is a **lot** of work, and it **really** isn't worth it except in extreme cases. But it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, if you'd like, you could use `internal` instead.

... and use `ObservableCollection<T>` and don't forget to set the DataContext of the view.

Comment: In my experience even internal accessibility is enough to break XAML data binding and only public properties can be bound to.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Relative Source binding, right now your binding is to the DataContext of your `ItemBuySellAddEdit` (FrameworkElement) Atleast that is my Impression, because you are using `partial`. If it is an ViewModel check the Output Window, and look if you have any binding errors.

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="xxx" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemBuySellAddEdit}},
        Mode=OneWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="ItemName"/>
```

But the Answer from Stephan Bauer still applies.

Also Take the answer from WaltiD into consideration if you want new items in that list to show up automatically.