# Inserting data into Data Grid View c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, datagridview

I am developing a diary application that allows user to insert appointments into a diary so they can see what others are doing during that week.

I've created an add appointments form which submits the appointment into the database successfully. But now i want to make these appointments visible in the data grid view under the correct date. As you can see by the attached photo the current week is along the top, and the users are down the side.

Any idea how i can make a start on this? I'm new to c# and SQL so its quiet a challenge...

[DGV where the appointments will be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH6hR.png)

[Add appointments form which adds the data to the database when submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxVMO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start from MVVM architecture pattern first

> https://www.wintellect.com/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained/

Use observation collection and set data in observation collection and with the help of binding the data will auto-update in data grid view

Use Binding to update data in the data grid

> [How to bind WPF DataGrid to ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539022/how-to-bind-wpf-datagrid-to-observablecollection)

For SQL learn some basic knowledge

> https://parallelcodes.com/wpf-mvvm-datagrid-bind-from-sql-database/