# WPF DataGrid Dymanic Column binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am new to WPF and got one problem. I am using `DataGrid` where row are fix (only 3 row) but column can be added at run time.

```
Row 1 :- Stock Name
Row 2 :- Current Price
Row 3 :- Old Price
```

and the Row 2 and 3 will get updated at `runtime` every second. i have class as below :-

```
class Stock
{
String name;
double currentPrice;
double oldPrice;
} 

class StockCollaction
{

List<Stock> list = new List<Stock>();

public void addStock(Stock stock)
{
list.add(stock);
}

public void update()
{
....
}
.....
}
```

I want to create `DataGrid` like below (Where each column need to bind with model, instead of row):-

[image: Data Grid]

please guide me how can i  get it done, any specific link to refer will be a great help, i think i have to use `MVVM`.

Comment: This really doesn't fit with the design of the built-in `DataGrid`.  Some third-party grids may support "inverted" axes like this.  Off the top of my head, I think the DevExpress grid does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to update the stock prices and add new stocks at runtime, `Stock` should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) and use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `List<Stock>`.

Expose the stock list via a [public property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087258/815938), from the post you can also learn how to set the `DataContext` and `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid. This is how `StockCollection class` looks like

```
public class StockCollection
{
    private ObservableCollection<Stock> stocks;
    public ObservableCollection<Stock> Stocks
    {
        get 
        { 
            return stocks; 
        }
    }
    //...add(), update() and other methods/properties
}
```

Now the XAML code.

Using the built-in `DataGrid` you add a new row, not a new column for a stock. You could find a 3rd party `DataGrid` that supports inverted axes, as Mike suggested in his comment, or - this is a funny part in learning WPF - you rotate the DataGrid by applying a `RotateTransform`.

In my code sample I define 2 DataGrid, one is normal, one is rotated 90 degrees. The code is modified from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133121/815938). You need to play with `DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle`, `DataGrid.LayoutTransform` and `DataGrid.CellStyle` to rotate the DataGrid.

[image: rotated DataGrid]

```
<StackPanel Margin="100">
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Width="200" Height="120" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Stocks}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Old Price" Binding="{Binding Path=OldPrice}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Current Price" Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentPrice}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Grid Height="100"></Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" Width="100" Height="500" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Stocks}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Old Price" Binding="{Binding OldPrice}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Current Price" Binding="{Binding CurrentPrice}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer i think this should work fine but i need custom height for row 1 because i need to display image in that. Can you please guide me how to set different height for rows?

Comment: You need to play with `DataTemplate`. I have uploaded a [demo project](http://1drv.ms/1tKHz46) for you to get started.

Comment: That was amazing help, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just one more small help how to set background color to row 2 at runtime as we have added image.

Comment: can i have your gmail id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63488/discussion-between-varun-jain-and-kennyzx).

Comment: I am not able to hide the scrollbar i tried `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ` but still scrollbar are showing.